# What kind of demon is in "My Status as an Assassin Obviously Exceeds the Hero's"?

Tags: japanese-language, my-status-as-an-assassin

In the manga *My Status as an Assassin Obviously Exceeds the Hero's*, the English translation refers to a "Demon Kingdom" and a "Demon King". Based on the wording in the original Japanese, which of the Japanese variations of "demon" are they referencing?

Do they use a foreign loan word, or are they referring to a specific type of demon out of Japanese folklore, such as a *yokai* or an *oni*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in @AkiTanaka's comment, the word translated as "Demon" in this manga is "ma" (魔), or "maō" (魔王) for Demon King and "[mazoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazoku)" (魔族) when discussing the demon kingdom.

I haven't personally read the Manga, but you can tell by comparing these panels from the first chapter:

[image: English panels with the text "Demon King"]

[image: Same panels in Japanese, with the text "maō" / "魔王"]

[image: More English panels, describing the demon kingdom and the other 3 kingdoms]

[image: Same panels in Japanese, with the text "mazoku" / "魔族"]

So no, the "demons" to which they're referring aren't a particular type of being from Japanese mythology, like "youkai" or "oni", but rather a more general term for evil spirits/beings often used in generic Fantasy settings.

It's the same "ma" used in "[akuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akuma_(folklore))" (悪魔), which you may have also seen in many Manga and Anime, and is often aligned with more Western/foreign notions of "demons" and "devils".

See e.g. [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32271) answer for some nuances of how of these various terms differ.